# Laravel, have a limited amount of post each day

Tags: forms, laravel, submit

I was wondering if Laravel has an implemented way to limit the submits of a form. I would like to work with a day limit that resets every day.

***So for example:***  I want to limit the submits of a referal form. Each user can refer 3 times a day.

How do I manage the amount of submits? And how do I reset the limit every day?

Answer (score 0):

When you're validating the form submission, you can query the database and count how many time this user (or IP address, or else, depending on what you use to track the users) submitted the form in the last day.

Laravel uses the `Carbon`  library, and it provides very easy way to get the date of "one day ago", you could use that for your query.

The specific implementation will depend on how you track users and when you reset - at a set hour once per day, or the time doesn't matter as long as they don't submit a form more than three times in 24 hours.